# Why navigation property in one to many relationship in model makes ModelState Invalid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

First of all I should say my code was working fine before transferring DataAccess (Db Context & Entity classes) to class library but after transfer The value of `ModelState.Isvalid` return's false because the navigation property (Category) in The Review model is null.

The problem will solved by adding an nullable annotation to Category property but my question is why this problem has arisen after using class library for DataAccess.

This is my Review Model :

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Category Model :

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Review> Review { get; set; }
}
```

This is my action :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddReview(Review review)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Enter required fields");

        await _uReviewService.AddReview(review);
        TempData["message"] = "success";
        return RedirectToAction("Comments");
    }
```

Comment: It couldn't be just moving the code to class library. Probably the class library project has NRT enabled (`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`) in the project file while the previous hasn't.